# Is $\int_0^{1/2} \! f(x)g(x) \, \mathrm{d} x$ an inner product on $C[0,1]$

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

I know $\displaystyle\int_0^1 f(x)g(x) \, dx $ is an inner product for $ C[0,1]$ but I can't find a conclusive answer either way for $\displaystyle\int_0^{1/2} f(x)g(x) \, d x$

Comment: I have enclosed your TeX in dollar signs $\$$ which make the output more readable.

Comment: Do you mean inner product on $C[0,1/2]$? If so, yes, it'll be the same argument as for $[0,1]$. If you mean on $C[0,1]$, think about this: can you find a function  on [0,1] that is not identically 0 whose 'inner product' norm is 0?

Comment: .... but on another hand, it is a semi-inner product.

Answer (score 2):

No, take 
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}0 & \text{ if } 0\le x\le\frac{1}{2}\\x-\frac{1}{2}&\text{ if }\frac{1}{2}\lt x\le1\end{cases} $$

Then $f\cdot f = 0$ but $f\neq 0$

Comment: You want $x-1/2$, otherwise $f \notin C[0,1]$.

Comment: ty, I've corrected it.